# Creating XML file on local server from php array by using DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm trying to create an XML file on my local server from a PHP array using DOMDocument, but I'm facing some problem, that is, a file doesn't want to create itself from my code.

I'm stuck and don't know what to do next to create that file, so any advice is more than welcome.

Below I attach my existing code, which is two files, first HTML with simple form and second PHP script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<form action="generetingXMLFile.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    <div id="row">
        <span>1</span>
        <input type="text" size="2" name="numbers[]">
        <input type="text" name="nicknames[]">
    </div>
    <div id="row">
        <span>2</span>
        <input type="text" size="2" name="numbers[]">
        <input type="text" name="nicknames[]">
    </div>
    <div id="row">
        <span>File's name:</span>
        <input type="text" name="fileName">
    </div>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And the PHP script look like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<?php

$numbers = $_POST["numbers"];
$nicknames = $_POST["nicknames"];
$ac = array_combine($numbers, $nicknames);
print_r ($ac);

$fileName = $_POST["fileName"];

$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xml -> preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml -> formatOutput = true;

$xmlTeam = $xml -> createElement("Team");

foreach ($ac as $key => $value) {
    $xmlPlayer = $xml -> createElement("Player");
    $xmlNumber = $xml -> createElement("Number", $key);
    $xmlNickname = $xml -> createElement("Nickname", $value);
    $xmlPlayer -> appendChild($xmlNumber);
    $xmlPlayer -> appendChild($xmlNickname);
    $xmlTeam -> appendChild($xmlPlayer);
}

$xml -> appendChild($xmlTeam);

$xml -> save($fileName.".xml");
if ($xml -> save($fileName.".xml") !== false) {
    echo "OK!";
}
else {
    echo "Error.";
}

echo "<p>".$xml -> saveXML()."</p>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

So: `Print_r` statement prints correctly, but `if` statement echoes "Error.", and `$xml -> saveXML()` echoes only `nodeValues`.

So as you can see the problem is about my `DOMDocument` statements in my opinion, but I can be wrong, because I'm still a newbie when it comes to programming, so I try to learn from every tip you are willing to provide.

Comment: Why do you use `save($fileName.".xml")` twice?

Comment: Does the account under which your PHP service runs access to the file location and the rights to write there? Print `$filename` to make sure what it is (is it an absolute path, or relative?), and try `file_put_contents($filename, "test")` to see if that returns `false` or `true`.